# How to change the date format in Jquery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to change the date format in Jquery/Javascript?

I've downloaded the 
[date.js](https://raw.github.com/vitch/jquery-methods/master/date.js). Then, I follow below example:

```
var d1 = Date.parse('2010-10-18, 10:06 AM');
alert(d1.toString('dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss GMT'));
```

So I write my own code for following date:

> Thu Jan 31 2013 16:29:30 GMT+0700 (WIT)

```
var d1 = Date.parse("Thu Jan 31 2013 16:29:30 GMT+0700 (WIT)");
alert(d1.toString('dd/mm/yyyy'));
```

My logcat prints this:

> CordovaLog(31455): Uncaught RangeError: toString() radix argument must
>   be between 2 and 36

I use Phonegap for my android application.

Comment: Try using moment instead. It's really good for date parsing and formatting http://momentjs.com/ I see momentjs as the closest we have to JodaTime in javascript. Another option is to use the date formater of the [jquery datepicker](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate), but I think momentjs is better.

Comment: I'm really interested with momentjs but the documentation is really long and I can't find any way to convert from timestamp to my formatted date.

Comment: moment(TimeStampInMillis).format('DD/MM/YYYY')

Answer (score 0):

try out this..

```
var d = new Date(); 
var newDate = d.getDate()+'/'+(d.getMonth()+1)+'/'+d.getFullYear();

alert('newDate '+newDate);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use JavaScript to format date and time. http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/10_ways_to_format_time_and_date_using_javascript.php3

```
function formatDate(date) {
    var d1 = Date.parse(date);
    var d = new Date(d1);
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    if (curr_date.toString().length == 1) {
        curr_date = "0" + curr_date;
    }
    var curr_month = d.getMonth();
    curr_month++;
    if (curr_month.toString().length == 1) {
        curr_month = "0" + curr_month;
    }
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    console.log(curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year);
}

formatDate("Thu Jan 31 2013 16:29:30 GMT+0700 (WIT)");
//Returns the date in "dd/mm/yyyy" format
```